# How to use docker arguments as arguments to a function inside it

Tags: docker, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I am trying to get the arguments from the docker image and then I want to use that argument as an argument to the function inside the docker.

For example:

```
CMD ["python", "xyz.py","--input=/input_data","--output=/output_data"]
```

I want to enter the locations of input and output commandline

or

```
CMD ["python", "add.py","--input1=4","--input2=5"]
```

I want to enter 4 and 5 from command line to get the sum as a result, in this way I can generalize my docker very well.

How can i do this?

Comment: If you pass the parameters in Dockerfile CMD statement means that once they are read, you have to build the Docker image and then run it (as a container). It makes no sense for me. Isn't it better to not to pass any argument to CMD and make that your python program read those parameters at runtime, so you don't have to build the image each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand, what you want is to create, in the second case, a container that adds two elements.

If I am right, and what you want to execute at the moment is something like:
 `docker run add:latest 4 6`

What you have to do is a script with the `python add.py` and include it as ENTRYPOINT, not in the CMD. Then you could call: `docker run add: latest 4 5` and get the sum of both.

The CMD can be *overwritten* in `docker run`. Look at this post:

http://www.johnzaccone.io/entrypoint-vs-cmd-back-to-basics/

Comment: Thank you, it helped!!!!. However, I have issue with default values of the arguments. If I want to change one of the arguments out of its default value, I need to write all the input arguments, which is painful.

Comment: You can control default values in the ENTRYPOINT script.